# ios app run on ipad, launchscreen.storyboard Rotate screen issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

iOS app ,set to allow only vertical screen, when running on iPad, when iPad is in horizontal screen，display is incomplete.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide more info like screen screenshot or some code

Comment: Please help me look at it @MohitKumar

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your .plist

Comment: Third picture above

Comment: You want to display in Horizontal mode on iPad or not?

Comment: I want it to force a portrait screen, but this problem occurs when the user launches the app when the iPad is in landscape mode

Comment: In your plist "Supported Interface Orientations (iPad)" remove other orientations from that list. Hope that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plist "Supported Interface Orientations (iPad)" remove other orientations from that list.

Hope that will solve your problem